# Change an entry in my Database with a HTML Button

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, input

I guess this is a quite simple question. If wrote my own Sign in and register PHP files which are quite secure and use the newest PHP "technology". Now, in my member area everybody has his 
own profile. The default profile is meant to be changed, when clicking onto settings.

On settings, you should be able the change a specific heading on your profile, so I added a database entry named: userheading
I added the user heading manually and it works perfectly fine (in phpmyadmin). 
All I want is a form (input and button) which is causing the database to change the entry depending on what the typed into the input field. When clicking the Button, this should run:

```
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET userheading=$uh1 WHERE id='$id'";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

I know that db_conx is not defined here, but everything exists in my file, so i do have a connection to this database. The variable $uh1 is not even defined but I should be exactly what the user typed in, here just the idea:

```
<input id="userheading1" type="text">
```

and somewhere in the PHP above define the post:

```
$uh1 = $_POST['userheading1']
```

So what do I have to do to trigger the PHP ? I know you could do it via Javascript but I don't think it is needed. Also, if it would be the best way, how can you do it ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sounds like a standard *form → submit → insert into database → display on webpage* scenario. If you already have a signup form working, what's the problem with this one exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="userheading1" name="userheading1" type="text">
```

You need to use `name` for your input if you want to pick it up by php. Id have nothing to do with it. Even if you will send it by JS you still need to give that variable a name in your ajax call.

Comment: Thank you, even if I have not solved the problem, this should actually help me to solve the problem in a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good thing that you use mysli but the query doesn't seem save, use parameter binding. if you make the form post to a php script with the code you want to execute it will do that for you (not the parameter binding, but  executing your code)